# Youtube Data API reduced to Zero Queries per day (Audit / Form)

Tags: youtube-api

i have a project on Google Cloud Platform, using the **Youtube Data V3 API**. Everything was going well, earlier this month after receiving several emails alerting that I had to do an Audit, the queries for the day stopped completely. they were completely zeroed.

I followed the link to perform the Audit, and i successfully completed all the changes that were told to me in my application, strictly following the regulations. The audit went well. No further changes were required from me.

But the issue is that the queries per day remain at zero. I can't edit. It occurred to me that maybe using the Google Cloud Trial there could be some change. Negative. I'm still unable to increase the limits, not even using the balance they give you as a gift.

The project used approximately a margin of about 25,000 to 300,000 queries / day. I have requested 500.000 queries / day filling in the quota expansion form to have a little more margin.

Meanwhile the project has been stopped for almost a month. If anyone knows something or how I should proceed about it,

Thank you very much.
Have a nice day,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related author should contact google about there verification process.  SO cant help with that.